# Rails forms: how to store two text_fields in one array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Newbie to rails and on many online tutorials I see this example

```
<div class="field">
 <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
 <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
 <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
 <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
</div>
```

which stores like this

```
"first_name"=>"foo", "last_name"=>"bar"
```

Is there a way use text_field or another form attribute to store two inputs in an array, so it would end up something like:

```
"name"=>["foo", "bar"]
```

This is not the preferred way, but curious to see how it would be done

Update

In your example you are passing @user.first_name and .last_name as the value. I was thinking more something more like this:

```
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label "First Name" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
 <%= f.label "Last Name" %><br />
 <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
```

where there is no `@user.first_name` but `@user.name[0]`

Comment: In your controller, you could combine them like `name = [params[:first_name], params[:last_name]]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `text_field_tag` to achieve this. (documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag)

A simple example would look like:

```
text_field_tag 'name[]', @user.first_name
text_field_tag 'name[]', @user.last_name
```

This will send both names under the `name` parameter. You can access the array with `params[:name]` in your controller.